# httpClient ReadAsStringAsync encoding problem

Tags: c#, .net

I've created a Net Core 3.1 API that returns DOCX, DOC, RTF, PDF files, generated from a string. My problem is encoding. Using CURL from the command line is no problem, but using my api, although the code of files opened in notepad is seemingly similar, there are differences:

1. Valid file with CURL Notepad opens with ANSI encoding and mine with UTF-8
2. Normal letters are the same in both cases, only those with dashes and dots differ
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfaAV.png)

I tried different coding changes but nothing helped, please help.
To retrieve the content of the file, I use:

```
string response = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

I've tried a few encoding changes but so far it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use something like this:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(uri);
var responseString = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(response, 0, response.Length - 1);
return responseString;
```

Comment: Instead of Unicode you may try UTF8 like this:  var responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response, 0, response.Length - 1);

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is encoding.

I think it's more than that. I think it's that you're trying to treat *opaque binary data* as a string to start with.

While RTF files are indeed text, all the other formats you mentioned (DOCX, DOC, PDF) are *binary*. Trying to treat arbitrary binary data as text will almost always lose information. You shouldn't be trying to store the data as a string - you should be reading it as a stream or a byte array. It's not clear what you're doing with the result afterwards, but if you're saving it to a file, I'd suggest opening a file stream, opening the response as a stream, and just using `Stream.CopyTo` to copy from the response to a file.

(As an aside, you should almost certainly be using `await` rather than the `Task.Result` property too.)